# Uncaught ReferenceError: TweenLite is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, css

/justincavery/pen/mPJadb   - it is link on codepan

When I copy code from codepan and run it. I have got error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: TweenLite is not defined".

Image is drawing once, but no animation...only if I press "F5". Help me)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Go to Settings->Javascript->Add External JavaScript and see what is there.
Codepen has the dependency included, and you didnt include it in your own code.

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```

Include this to your file.